# Return all paths of desired keys in a python dictionary instead of first found

Tags: python, dictionary, search, path, generator

I'm trying to look for all occurrences of a key in dictionary. Currently I've figured out how to create a generator that will print only the first one, but I'm not sure how to return all of them to a object or somehow be able to use generator comprehension. How do I return all the intended data to a usable object?

```py
t = {'a': 1,
     'b': {'f': 'asfdsf'},
     'c': 3,
     'd': [
        {'a': 1,
         'b': 2,
         'c': 
            {'e': 1},
         'd': 
            {'e': 55}}],
     'g': 2}

def niah(haystack, needle, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []
    if isinstance(haystack, dict):
        if needle in haystack:
            #print(path)
            path.append(needle)
            return(path)
        for k, v in haystack.items():
            result = niah(v, needle, path + [k])
            if result is not None:
                return result
    elif isinstance(haystack, list):
        for idx, v in enumerate(haystack):
            result = niah(v, needle, path + [idx])
            if result is not None:              
                return result
```

Output:

```
>>> niah(t, 'e'))
['d', 0, 'c', 'e']
```

Desired:

```
>>> niah(t, 'e'))
[['d', 0, 'c', 'e'], ['d', 0, 'd', 'e']] # or some kind object accessible by iteration, aka generator
```

Yielding path seems to just make generators in a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable `pathlist=[]`. and instead of returning, just `pathlist.append(path)` (or `result`, or whatever).

Comment: It's a viable option but I'm trying to make it a portable function. Global variables are bad practice.

Comment: @bijenkins Fine, then define a class and make this a class variable.